# Kcfinder in CKeditor

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, ckeditor, kcfinder

I know there are more topics about this but there seems to be no one exactly like mine.

I have Ckeditor added to my site and want to use Kcfinder as file-manager. I have copied the files of Kcfinder into the Ckeditor-directory (ckeditor->kcfinder) and updated ckeditor's config.js like described on kcfinder's website. Also i gave full permission to the uploadfolder of kcfinder.

When i click on the image-button in Ckeditor and then the browse-button i get an error: You don't have permissions to browse server. Does anyone know what to do here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should edit your kc finder's config file like below:

- 'disabled' = false

but now you have a security problem. you have to check your authentication in this config file